# MVC datetime localization issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, localization

In our application we store a culture on the user. For example "en-US".
Then when we display dates in a view we do like this:

```
date.ToString("d", user.CultureInfo)
```

which results in that the user sees the date the way he prefers.
The user of course inputs dates in the same way. For example a US date "12/1/2014" which is December 1st 2014.
When MVC tries to convert this automatically and the MVC thread runs another culture than the user prefers it was converted wrong at first. This date was by accident converted to January 12th 2014.
To fix this problem I created a custom DateTime model binder:

```
public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
    var date = value.ConvertTo(typeof(DateTime), HttpContext.Current.UserContext().CultureInfo);
    return date;
}
```

now we convert the dates with help of the users actual culture.
But this unfortunately causes another problem. In different views we have for example a hidden input like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.created)
```

This will be written with the default culture of the MVC thread (1.12.2014). But when the user posts data back then the custom model binder will try to convert the date by the users culture and that conversion goes wrong.
I could fix this by in the view code like this instead (or format it with the users culture):

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.created, new { @Value = Model.created.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") })
```

because this date format will always be correct it seems.
But I would like to avoid searching all code trying to find all places I need to change. And it's for sure that I will have bugs left.
Localization it's very common so it seems that I'm missing something. It should be an easier way to approach the problem.
If it's not then how could I solve the latter problem I've created? Is there a way to output these dates the same way through some global setting without having to change every line of code that is affected by this?

Comment: Could you, in your custom binder use `DateTimepRaseExact` to convert the string to a `DateTime` passing formats from the user's culter (`CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern` *and* the applicable one for the hidden fields? However if the hidden fields are `dd/mm/yyyy` and the customer's `mm/dd/yyyy` ambiguities and inevitable (better to use ISO format for all non-user seem dates).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use view models to display only the properties you want to display and edit. It is unnecessary to send data to the client and send it back to the server when it should not even be modified. Your just increasing data transfer both ways and opening yourself to overposting attacks. In the POST method, get the data model, update only the properties you need and save it.

This would solve the problem (prevention is better than cure) but if you do want to include hidden inputs, you could make it a little more robust by creating a custom html helper, say

```
 public static MvcHtmlString UIDateForFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, isHidden = false)
```

where based in the value of `isHidden` the output would either be a hidden input or a textbox, with the value attribute set to the correct value for your custom model binder. For example, for the snippet for hidden input might look like

```
ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
if (isHidden)
{
  TagBuilder input = new Tagbuilder("input");
  input.MergeAttribute("type", "hidden");
  input.MergeAttribute("name", name);
  input.MergeAttribute("value", metaData.Model.ToString(helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.UserContext().CultureInfo));
  return MvcHtmlString.Create(input.ToString());
}
else
{
  ....
```

Then use as

```
@Html.UIDateFor(m => m.MyEditableDate) // input type=text" (or browser datepicker if type="date")
@Html.UIDateFor(m => m.Created, true) // input type="hidden"
```

You could also consider including another element or label that renders information about the expected format if its editable.

However even this is not addressing other potential problems with what your trying to do, in particular unobtrusive client side validation.

Comment: I guess posting data back and forth saves me from another database call when validating models etc. Maybe it's better to change that strategy. I should probably look into why I'm doing like this and as you point out, just the fact that I post non editable data to the client and back could be a problem itself. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options -

1. Use standard DateTime Patterns

   ```
   Model.created.ToString("d")
   ```

   In this case your date will be formatted culture- specific.
2. Use custom Parser for Date - e.g

   ```
   public static DateTime ParseExactLocalized(string dateString)
   {
       try
       {
           var mask = DateMaskServer;
           var formatsCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
           DateTime dt;
           if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, mask, formatsCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
               return dt;

           return DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, mask, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
       }
       catch (FormatException ex)
       {
           throw new FormatException("Wrong date format.", new FormatException(string.Format("Could not parse DateTime. Value: {0}", dateString), ex));
           //throw new FormatException(string.Format("Could not parse DateTime. Value: {0}, Mask: {1}", dateString, mask), ex);                
       }
   }
   ```

In your case US format will be parsed using Invariant culture

Comment: How could this work. If the user posts back 31/12/2014 representing 31st December in their culture (dd/MM/yyyy), this will fail if the server culture is invariant or en-US (MM/dd/yyy). In any case it too late because the model binder has already tried and failed to bind the date.

Comment: This will work if you have your model properties as String, not DateTime. Having property as string may be useful for date pickers and cases described above.

Comment: Use a `string` for a date instead of `DateTime` - are you serious? (and it should not be used with a datepicker)

Comment: Why not? What is wrong with that if you need custom format for date?
Actually you have date time fields, but do not expose them to  your view.